# Is there a bijection $f: N \times N \rightarrow U \subset N$ with $f(x,y)+f(u,v)=f(x+u,y+v)$ and $f(x,y) \cdot f(u,v)=f(x \cdot u, y \cdot v)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, semirings

Is there a subset of natural numbers that has the same additive and multiplicative structure as the set of ordered pairs of natural numbers under the classical operations of addition and multiplication i.e. is there a (primitive recursive) bijection $f: N \times N \rightarrow U \subset N$ with $f(x,y)+f(u,v)=f(x+u,y+v)$ and $f(x,y) \cdot f(u,v)=f(x \cdot u, y \cdot v)$?

Obviously $f(x,y)=2^x \cdot 3^y$ is not a solution: $2^1 \cdot 3^1 + 2^1 \cdot 3^1 = 2^{1+1} \cdot 3^{1+0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bijection satisfying the addition and multiplication
identities. In fact, even
without the assumption that $f$ is a bijection
there
are only three functions satisfying both identities: for all $x$ and $y$
either 
$f_1(x,y) = x$, $f_2(x,y) = y$ or $f_3(x,y) = 0$.

To see this, use the addition identity repeatedly to deduce that
(i) $f(a,b)$ $=$ $f(a+0,0+b)$ $=$ $f(a,0)+f(0,b) = a\cdot f(1,0)$ $+$ $b\cdot f(0,1)$. In particular,
(ii) $f(1,1) = f(1,0)+f(0,1)$. Now the multiplication identity
yields that $f(1,1)\cdot f(1,1) = f(1,1)$, so $f(1,1)\in \{0,1\}$,
since $0$ and $1$ are the only multiplicative idempotents.
If $f(1,1)=0$, then by (ii) we get $f(1,0)+f(0,1)=0$, forcing $f(1,0)=0=f(0,1)$. Hence by (i) we
get $f(a,b)=0$ for any $a$ and $b$. ($f=f_3$).

On the other hand, if $f(1,1)=1$, then by (ii) we get either
(x) $f(1,0)=1$ and $f(0,1) = 0$ or (y) $f(1,0)=0$ and $f(0,1) = 1$.
If (x), then (i) yields $f(a,b)=a$ for any $a$ and $b$ ($f=f_1$),
while if (y),
then (i) yields $f(a,b)=b$ for any $a$ and $b$ ($f=f_2$).

Comment: So, though one can construct and interpret the arithmetic of integers and fractions from the arithmetic of ordered pairs of natural numbers, the addition and multiplication of integers (or fractions) is not identical to the addition and multiplication of any subset of natural numbers i.e. no natural number can itself simultaneously play both the role of a natural number and the role of an integer?

Comment: @John: I may be missing the point of your comment, but the arithmetics of rational numbers as ordered pairs of natural numbers is not the one you described because $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\neq\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ in general. Notice though that the (restricted) map described in the answer $(x,1)\mapsto x$ gives you the expected identification, for $\frac{x}{1}=x$.

Comment: The arithmetic of fractions as ordered pairs is derivable from the arithmetic of ordered pairs of natural numbers: $\frac{x}{1+y} = \frac{u}{1+v}$ iff $x \cdot (1+v) = u \cdot (1+y)$ iff $0 = \vert (x, 1+y) \square (u,1+v) \vert$ with $(x,y) \square (u,v) = (x \cdot v, y \cdot u)$ and $\vert (x,y) \vert = \vert x - y \vert$. My claim is that no natural number can play both the role of a natural number and the role of an integer for it would ultimately require a function of the above type. There may not be space for me to explain my position, and it may not ultimately matter. Thank you though.